# Scrolling under a transparent fixed element

Tags: html, css

[The problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bDGa.png)

I am working on a page with a fixed header that has transparent background. And i need to make the content below it somehow when scrolled under this fixed header disappear like how it would act if the header was non-transparent.

EDIT:
Fixed it by adding the same background to the transparent fixed element as the body and by adding properties

```
background-position: center top;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Why would you make it transparent if you need exactly the opposite behavior?

Comment: Because there is a background in the body that needs to stay consistent.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I don't understand what "needs to stay constistent" means. Should it be transparent at first and only when scrolled, somewhere farther down, cover up the the background?

Comment: Not really. Something like this [link](https://imgur.com/a/y7CqSWn)

Comment: The title Notification and its background simply cover image + input (or what that white thing should be?). I'm pretty sure you should rethink the use of the transparent header

Comment: I might have to do that, thank you for your input

Answer (score 0):

indeed, setting a background on the header with the background-position attribute works but I think it would be slightly better in your case to fix the rest of the content in place and set its overflow to scroll